Am I supposed to delete old texts on a regular basis?
As a normal Android end user, am I supposed to regularly delete old texts? I've noticed my text messaging app (Textra) is getting slower and slower as time goes by, and is now nearly unusable.
If this is a normal android maintenance process, what is the correct method for deleting texts? I've tried deleting texts in Textra, but later I see them show up again, ie, in contacts, each contact shows the most recent texts to and from a contact. If I deleted all texts from Textra, how are these recent texts still showing up here? What is the correct method?

Yes, you need to regularly delete old text messages.  Otherwise, as you are experiencing, text messaging apps (especially ones like Textra) can get painfully slow.
You can perform this purging manually, or have an app do it for you.
If you would like Textra to do this automatically for you, click on the 3-dot button in its upper-right corner.  Then click on Settings.  Scroll to the bottom of the Settings page, and you'll see a More Stuff section.  Within that section, you'll see Messages to Keep.  Click on that item.  You'll then be presented with a screen that allows you to specify the maximum number of regular text messages and the maximum number of media messages to keep for every thread.  Note that recovery is usually not possible, so be careful.
The reason deleted texts may still get shown is because Android is rather limited in regards to how it handles text and media messages.  Due to Android's limitations, apps like Textra don't actually replace the text messaging system.  Instead, they add another layer.  Thus, the native text messaging system and this extra layer have to handle message deletion together.  This often has issues, resulting in deleted messages not really getting deleted.  The only workaround is to go into the native text messaging app and delete messages from there too.  This known issue can result in significant privacy problems.
